# supported protocol with Node mqtt 2.14.0 vs org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3

Tags: mqtt

Why nodeJS supports the following protocol and why not paho client

Mqtt nodejs vs org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3

Why Nodejs supports the following protocols
mqtt.connect([url], options)
The URL can be on the following protocols: 'mqtt', 'mqtts', 'tcp', 'tls', 'ws', 'wss'.

And Paho supports Only tcp && ssl
MqttClient.connect(options)
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if the URI does not start with
* "tcp://", "ssl://" or "local://".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Paho client should now accept `ws://` and `wss:/` as it has MQTT over Websocket support. Earlier versions didn't so it made sense to throw an error if you try to specify these transports. The update to the doc probably just got missed ([issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/659) opened to fix).

`tcp://` and `ssl://` are legacy from the original IBM Java MQTT client from which the Paho client pulls a lot of inspiration if not actual code.

`mqtt://` and `mqtts://` were not formally on the IANA list but a formal request has been made as part of the MQTT v5 spec so once the next version of the client is formally released support v5 the client will support them. ref: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/464